# Why is the verb (stehen) in this position?

Tags: verb, position

Why is the verb "stehen" in this position?

> Wellness ist kein gesetzlich geschützter Begriff, **steht** jedoch für ein ganzheitliches Gesundheitskonzept, welches auf Wohlbefinden, Spaß und einer guten körperlichen Verfassung basiert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a contraction of two sentences:

> 1. Wellness ist kein gesetzlich geschützter Begriff.
> 2. Wellness steht jedoch für ein ganzheitliches Gesundheitskonzept, ...

Both sentences share the same subject (*»Wellness«*) and both of them have it at position 1. So, you can join the sentences by omitting the second appearance of the subject:

> Wellness ist kein gesetzlich geschützter Begriff, steht jedoch für ein ganzheitliches Gesundheitskonzept, ...

You can do this in english as well:

> Tom cooks well.
> Tom takes care of his friends.
> Tom is a good father.

You can combine these three sentences to one:

> Tom cooks well, takes care of his friends and is a good father.

And this works exactly identical in German:

> Tom kocht gut.
> Tom kümmert sich um seine Freunde.
> Tom ist ein guter Vater.

> Tom kocht gut, kümmert sich um seine Freunde und ist ein guter Vater.

Comment: Thank you very much